# If an input contains custom word, hide the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input[type=text] area and i'll paste/type a URL in it.

If pasted/typed url contains http, i want to hide $('#button') element.
If its not, keep showing the button also.
Thanks for any help.

Here is my demo code so far:

```
$('#pasteUrl').on('input', function () {
  var str = $('#pasteUrl').val();
  if (str.indexOf("http") !== -1) {
    $('#button').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Added "propertychange" to events as suggested by OP in the comments.

```js
$('#pasteUrl').on('input propertychange', function (ev) {
  var str = $(ev.currentTarget).val();
  if (str.indexOf("http") != -1) {
    $('#button').hide();
  } else {
    $('#button').show();
  }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="pasteUrl" />
<button id="button">Go</button>
```

Comment: Typing is ok but try pasting a http on it. Doesnt work with paste

Comment: It is working for me pasting, in Firefox and Chrome (Windows 10).

Comment: I tried on incognito page, worked fine like you said, probably its about my extensions.
But $('#pasteUrl').on('input propertychange', function (ev) will solved all

Comment: I added your solution to the answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely what you want - using [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```js
$('#pasteUrl').on('input propertychange', function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  $('#button').toggle(str.indexOf("http") == -1);
});
```